# Java symbol not found when it should be

Tags: java, ascii

here's my code:

```
    for(int i=0; i<plainTextUpper.length()-1; i++)
    {
      System.out.println(charCodeAt(i));
    }
```

It won't compile though, because it says charCodeAt's symbol was not found. Am I missing a library? The only one I have imported right now is java.util.*

Comment: You're mixing Java with JavaScript?

Comment: Is this Javascript or Java?

Comment: Oh, gosh, you guys are right - my mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is Java and not Javascript, you probably want this:

```
for(int i=0; i<plainTextUpper.length()-1; i++)
{
    System.out.println(plainTextupper.codePointAt(i));
}
```

Note that this will not process the last character of `plainTextUpper`. You probably also want to either get rid of the `-1` or change the comparison operator to `<=` in the `for` termination test.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm used to C# and JS; I forgot I wasn't using JS anymore!